# Creating a clickable div dynamically with Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I want the display the user an image, with a varying number of divs (depending on the number of faces detected) which should be clickable (a click on a face will show some attributes for that particular face).

So ideally I would like to create some divs (or buttons) around each face and have something like (click)="divClicked()" for each element. 
However,(click) isn't a legit attribute, so, for example, trying something like

```
d3.select('button').attr('(click)','onClickMe()');
```

gives an error. onclick is a legit attribute, but by using it I think I should break the way Angular wants me to work (as putting the function inside the component's ts file gives the error onClickMe is not defined).

The very best workaround I could come up with is to assign an id to each div and then do something like

```
document.getElementById('b1').onclick=this.onClickMe;
```

but that feels like bad coding.

So, what's the clean way to do that?

Comment: Do you have a Stackblitz for this?

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera No, my IDE is Visual Studio Code (and my OS is Ubuntu).

Comment: I mean can you create a sample project replicating this issue on StackBlitz?

https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular

Comment: Oh! Later on if that's necessary (as I will need to create some fake data rather than copy the entire code dealing with the json data from the server) but the question itself is about clean coding rather than about a specific project/code.

Comment: Why don't you think that `(click)` is legit?

Comment: It's not an actual html attribute, and from other answers I think (not sure) that syntax like (click) or [data] might be compiled by Angular. Anyways (as I mentioned in the question) i did try to add dynamically (with d3) it and got an error message.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you should create the `div` elements by adding a loop with `ngFor` to  your template [to display your divs](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data). Of course they may be CSS-styled, based on some properties you have determined beforehand (in particular the CSS properties `left` and `top` are useful here). Of course you can add a `(click)`-event to those `div`s too.

To do this, your component should hold a list of objects to display which you may update when necessary. Furthermore it should offer a method which gets called when the user wants to see details of a particular face.
The template then only cares for turning those objects into a HTML structure and bind the callbacks.

Structurally something similar to the following will occur in your template:

```
<div
    *ngFor="let face of faces; index as i"
    (click)="showFaceDetails(i)"
    [style.left.px]="face.x"
    [style.top.px]="face.y"
></div>
```

Comment: That was helpful, althought I must say that since the page I'm building is responsive (so left top etc. have to be based on the actual image shape in relation to the original image) I don't think that setting those attributes with ngFor is feasible. (Actually right now I set them with an img.onload function which feels like bad coding by itself, but I'm not sure if actual clean coding is possible when it comes to front end :P)